# Adding .htaccess file shows directory listing instead of redirecting to index.html, plus the directory listing is weird

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

Before I added a `.htaccess` file, if I typed in `https://example.com/f/myfolder`, it would redirect to `https://example.com/f/myfolder/` (with a trailing slash). `{documentRoot}/f` is a symlink to a folder that contains a folder named `myfolder`, and `myfolder` contains an `index.html` file.

I then added the `.htaccess` file into `{documentRoot}/f/myfolder` with the contents:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /f/myfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /f/myfolder/index.html [L]
```

Now if I type `https://example.com/f/myfolder` I get a directory listing instead of being redirected. If I type `https://example.com/f/myfolder/` the rewrites work as expected.

The weird thing is that the directory listing shows the contents of `{documentRoot}/f/myfolder`, and the title is "Index of f/myfolder" but if I hover over (say) the index.html file, it points to `https://example.com/f/index.html` instead of `https://example.com/f/myfolder/index.html` (and if I click it, it takes me to the `index.html` that is in the parent folder).

I tried prepending

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/f/myfolder/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L]
```

to the `.htaccess` file, to try and add a trailing slash, but it didn't seem to make any difference.

One final tidbit of information. If I change `+FollowSymLinks` to just `FollowSymLinks`, I get a 403 forbidden page instead of the directory listing. EDIT: I am changing it in the apache2 config file, in the `<Directory>` section for the directory. The only other option in that section is `AllowOverride All`

I am curious as to why the directory listing is weird, but my real question is: How can I make it work both with and without trailing slashes?

Using Apache/2.4.29

EDIT: One more discovery, not sure if it helps. If I have a blank `.htaccess` file, then `https://example.com/f/myfolder` gets redirected to `https://example.com/f/myfolder/`. If I add `RewriteEngine On` to the `.htaccess` file and nothing else, the redirect no longer happens.

EDIT 2: It's definitely related to `/f` being a softlink. If I add an Alias in the apache2 config file so that it's aliased to the correct directory instead of softlinked, then it works fine. I would prefer to fix it in the `.htaccess` file if possible though!

Comment: I can't really tell what you are actually trying to achieve here. What exactly are you trying to fix/get working here, that didn't _before_ you added the .htaccess file?

Comment: I want to send all URLs for that folder (`/f/myfolder`, `/f/myfolder/`, `/f/myfolder/*`) to the `index.html` file in that folder. Before the `.htaccess` file, `/f/myfolder/test` would be 404 not found. After the `.htaccess` file it ends up at `index.html`.

Comment: "If I **change** `+FollowSymLinks` to just `FollowSymLinks`" - Where are you _changing_ that? What other directives do you have? By removing the `+` you will remove any options that have been set in a parent config. (You can't mix `+`/`-` and non-prefix options.) Is the target of the symlink outside of the public HTML space? The appending of the trailing slash is controlled by mod_dir (and the `DirectorySlash` directive). The "weird" directory listing is expected behaviour if the trailing slash is omitted.

Comment: "If I type `https://example.com/f/myfolder/` the rewrites work as expected." - When you request the directory itself (ie. `/f/myfolder/`) then the rewrites don't actually do anything. `index.html` is served by mod_dir (`DirectoryIndex`). Only when requesting `/f/myfolder/something` should the rewrites kick into action. `https://example.com/f/myfolder` (without a trailing slash) will indeed trigger a directory listing, even when the directory contains a `DirectoryIndex` document.

Comment: @MrWhite - my bad I should have put that in the post (I'll edit in a sec). It's in the `<Directory>` section of the apache config. The only other thing in that section is `AllowOverride All`. I changed it based on some google searching to add the `+`  to see if it made a difference, which is how I got to the directory listing. The target of the symlink is technically outside the public HTML space, but relatively it is not. What I mean is that the document root is a symlink to outside the public HTML space, but the softlink is a relative `../folder`, so it doesn't move outside of it again.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, you are correct of course, what I meant was the `.htaccess` file works as expected for any url starting with `https://example.com/f/myfolder/`. I am not clear as to why simply adding `RewriteEngine On` to the `.htaccess` file changes the behavior of `https://example.com/f/myfolder`